# PostgreSQL: How to unify versions?

Tags: postgresql

On my Kubuntu machine, locally I was running PostgreSQL in a user-defined directory. Actually, an upgrade from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 provided PostgreSQL12. Actually, I have:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)

$sudo -u postgres psql
[sudo] Passwort: 
psql (12.6 (Ubuntu 12.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), server 10.16 (Ubuntu 10.16-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
```

What do I have to do, to unify this (to version 12) without losing data in the user-defined directory? There are two version 10 packages (PostgreSQL-10 and PostgreSQL-client-10) and the same ones version 12: Is it OK and sufficient to remove the two from 10?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is free to change how it stores data between versions. So just moving/copying the data directory is highly unlikely to be sufficient.

The simplest solution is to basically dump the data and then load it into the new server. If you start your new server running on a different port and different data directory, you can do this as one-liner.

```
pg_dumpall -p 5432 | psql -d postgres -p 5433
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/upgrading.html#UPGRADING-VIA-PGDUMPALL

If you have a lot of data, and you need to keep your database available during the upgrade then you may wish to look into logical replication.

Comment: Thank you! But what about my user defined data-directory:  
`$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory                Log file`  

10  main    5432 online postgres /mnt/Daten/Technik/PostgreSQL /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log`  

`12  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main   /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log`

Comment: What about your data directory? It's mounted in a different location, so it's safe from being written to by version12. pg_dumpall turns your version10 data into a text format, and then you load it into your version12 server with psql, which writes to the standard postgres data directory heirarchy.

Comment: postgres=# SHOW data_directory;  
`/mnt/Daten/Technik/PostgreSQL`  

e.g. I don't have a version ID in the datadir actually. So my concern is to mess up the two versions?